# Creating multiple logs in log4j causing weird effects

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to create multiple logs in Log4j, but I am facing a weird problem. Here's the log4j.properties and the code implementing it.

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILEALL

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILEALL=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEALL.File=${logfile.name}
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILEALL.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout

#log4j.appender.FILEMAIN=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.File=${logfilemain.name}
#log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
```

I have added the statement when running both and removed the original one

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILEALL , FILEMAIN
```

And this is the java code:

```
System.setProperty("logfile.name", savePath1);
// System.setProperty("logfilemain.name", savePath1);
logger = Logger.getLogger(HarishLog.class.getName());
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

The code works perfectly fine till I make one log, but as soon as I enable the setting for 2nd log in either the properties or the javafile, nothing happens.

Besides I am unable to put a different name at

```
log4j.appender.FILEALL.File=${logfile.name}
```

it only works for `logfile.name` and `logfilea.name`, It doesn't work for any other name if I change it both in the javacode and the properties folder. Why is this???

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILEALL, FILEMAIN

log4j.appender.FILEALL=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEALL.File=${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.FILEALL.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout

log4j.appender.FILEMAIN=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.File=${logfilemain.name}
log4j.appender.FILEMAIN.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
```

---

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.setProperty("logfile.name", "logall.txt");
        System.setProperty("logfilemain.name", "logmain.txt");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());
        logger.info("hello");
    }
}
```

If you're still having problems, try adding:

```
log4j.debug = true
```

to the beginning of your log4j.properties, and check the output messages.

Comment: Unable to do it. I have the same codes and this in savepaths

        String savePath1="F:\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\logtesting\\dist\\a.html";

        String savePath2="F:\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\logtesting\\dist\\b.html";

Only one file is created i.e a.html

Comment: Tried the .debug still no benefit only one file is created

Comment: If you're not getting log4j messages in the standard output, then it means log4j was not configured with that properties file (but possibly with a different one)

Comment: Oh yeah, there was a different instance which was being used and the current one was being ignored. Thank you for your help